# TP-Link switch redundancy

Tags: networking, switch, network-topology

At the moment we have 12 switches of the type **TP-LINK TL-SG1024DE**. These switches are connected in serie now, which means when one in the middle goes down that all the others in the chain will loose Internet access.

I want to connect the switches in **MESH** so that they are redundant and the network will remain working except for the downed switch.

[image]
<sub>(source: [pace.edu](https://webpage.pace.edu/ms16182p/networking/mesh2.jpg))</sub>

When I connected the network to the MESH topology I got the problem that the whole network went down. This was probably the cause of looping.

How can I configure the TP-LINK switches to enable the topology MESH?

Manual of the switch: [Click](https://static.tp-link.com/res/down/doc/TL-SG105E_V2_UG.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be able to use layer-2 switched network while having loops, you need to enable [STP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_Tree_Protocol) (Spanning Tree Protocol).

If your switches don't support such protocol, it is not possible to configure your network by introducing any loop.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I searched the manual and can't find the feature in this model.